# How to find out element names within pop-up windows?

Tags: html, popup

I'm testing a website. When I enter the URL, before the homepage loads, I get a pop-up window asking me to log in with a username and password. I need to find the names of the elements in this pop-up window.

Unfortunately, it is one of those "block everything else" pop-up windows that doesn't let me change tabs or open Firefox' menu.

I normally use Firebug for identifying a page element's name, but in this instance it's doing nothing to help.

I tried RESTClient and JMeter Proxy Recorder (aka HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder / HTTP Proxy Server), but neither of them could give me the information I need. I'm running out of ideas.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you referring to a prompt box? because those aren't elements you can access. ur description as a "block everything" pop up leads me to believe this is so.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the popup window for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modal dialogs prompting for credentials usually stand for authentication challenge which can be:

- [Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)
- [NTLM](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/N/NTLM.html)
- [Kerberos](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/)

Modal dialogs are part of the browser UI and can't be inspected using Firebug, because Firebug can just inspect elements within a website.

Basic Authentication can be bypassed by injecting credentials into URL like:

```
http://username:password@host.domain
```

However the right way to deal with all aforementioned authentication challenges is using JMeter's [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager). Being properly configured it constructs and sends a correct HTTP Header containing authorization details along with the request.

For details on how to configure HTTP Authorization Manager for different authentication types see [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) guide.

Comment: Thanks. Injecting credentials into the URL works for my purposes. I didn't try the other methods but I'll have a look at them soon.